# Android Animated Turns

Tags: android, rotateanimation

I'm using the following code to make turns (left or right) in a series. So if i call it one after another ie: `turn(90); turn(90); turn(-90);` all it shows is the last one. I'd like to show them all and it wait until the first one is done before moving on to the next. Any idea's?

```
public void turn(int i)
{

    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation( currentRotation, currentRotation + i,
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
                                                currentRotation = (currentRotation + i) % 360;

    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true);

    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    token.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did was create a que of the animations and an iterator to run through it... after i defined all the animations that needed to be done, added them to the que, i ran the first one, then within the AnimationListener handled the rest.

```
Queue<RotateAnimation> que = new LinkedList<RotateAnimation>();
Iterator<RotateAnimation> queIt;


public void turnToken(int i){

    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation( currentRotation, currentRotation + i,
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
                                                currentRotation = (currentRotation + i) % 360;

    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true);
    anim.setAnimationListener(this);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);

    que.add(anim);
}
```

AnimationListener:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(queIt.hasNext()){
        token.startAnimation((Animation) queIt.next());
        }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```